# Translate FormGroup.statusChanges into boolean Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am struggling to find an elegant way to translate Angular's `myForm.StatusChanges` into a simpler `Observable<boolean>` indicating if the form is valid:

```
this.valid$ = new Observable<string>();
const validObs$ = valid$.pipe(map( x => {
    console.log('x is: ' + x);
    return 'VALID' === x;
  }));

// This following line happens somewhere else, as soon as myForm is set
this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(this.valid$);
// Consume validObs$ wherever needed
```

I am pretty sure there is a better, more elegant, direct way in order to translate `statusChanges` into an simple boolean Observable?

**Edit**: I should re-evaluate my question as follows: How can I create an `Observable<boolean>` (mapping form status) and bind that at a later stage to `myForm.statusChanges`? Please note that in my example, the Observable is not of type boolean, but string.

**Edit 2:** 
Ok, I came up with this

```
// In ctor:
this.mySubject = new Subject<boolean>();
// Later on, somewhere else
this.myForm.statusChanges.pipe(map(s => 'VALID' === s)).subscribe(this.subject);
```

I think this is what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to init another observable, just return from existing:

```
formValid$(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.myForm.statusChanges.pipe(map(status => status === 'VALID'));
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that `myForm` is not ready in an early stage - updated my initial question. I think there is not much way around it ...